# How to show message when negative number is entered?

Tags: c++

I am coming to a problem where when negative numbers are entered that it shows an error message. **libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::bad_alloc: std::bad_alloc**. is there a way to detect that error when negative numbers and entered with a message: Enter 0 or greater. So, can anyone help me solve this. Thanks for the help.

I tried by doing this:

```
int students = 0;
    while (students <= 0) {
     cout << "How many students? ";
        cin >> students;
    if (students <= 0) {
      cout << "Enter 0 or greater"; 
    }
}

  int testsScore = 0;
 while (testsScore <= 0) {
     cout << "How many tests per student? "; 
           cin >> testsScore;
   if (testsScore <= 0) {
     cout << "Enter 0 or greater"; 
    }
}
```

Main Code:

```
#include <iostream>  // input out stream library. 
#include <iomanip> // parametic manipulators library for our table. 


using namespace std;

//MARK: Structure to use the following data given in the instructions. 
struct student_information {

    //MARK: Student name.
    string studentName; 

    //MARK: Student ID number.
    int id; 

    //MARK: Pointer to an array of test scores.
    int *tests; 

    //MARK:Average test score.
    double average; 

    //MARK: Course grade.
    char grade; 

   };

//MARK: The main() method should keep a list of test scores for group of students. 
int main() {

    // MARK: Declare variables. 
    int numberOfStudents; 
    int testScores; 

    //MARK: So, in our logic it should ask the user how many test scores there are to be, 
    // and how many students there are. 
    // It should then dynamically allocate an array of structures. However, 
    // each structure tests member should point to a dynamically allocated array
    // that will hold the test scores according to our instructions. 

    cout << "How many students?"; 
    cin >> numberOfStudents; 
    cout << endl; 

     cout << "How many tests per student? "; 
    cin >> testScores; 
    cout << endl;





   student_information *pointerToArray = new student_information[numberOfStudents];

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStudents; i++) {

        pointerToArray[i].tests = new int[testScores];

    }




    //MARK: So, this is when the array has been allocated, 
    //the program should ask for the student ID number and all the scores for each 
    // every student. 
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStudents; i++) {

        cout << "Student Name: "; 
        cin >> pointerToArray[i].studentName;
        cout << endl; 



        cout << "ID Number: "; 
        cin >> pointerToArray[i].id; 
        cout  << endl;





        for (int v = 0; v < testScores; v++)  {
            cout << " Test # " << (v + 1) << " : "; 


            //MARK: Checking to see all the data is entered for each student / member. 
            cin >> pointerToArray[i].tests[v];
            cout << endl; 

            // MARK: Checking if negative numbers  are entered for any test scores. 
            while(pointerToArray[i].tests[v] < 0 || pointerToArray[i].tests[v] > 100)  {

                cout << "Enter 0 or greater"; 
                cin >> pointerToArray[i].tests[v]; 
               cout << endl; 

            }















       }
    }
    //MARK: The average test score should be calculated and stored in the average member of each structure. 
    //The course grade should be computed on the basis of the following grading scale:
    // Average Test Grade     Course Grade
    // 91-100                          A
    // 81-90                           B
    // 71-80                           C
    // 61-70                           D
    // 60 or below                     F

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStudents; i++) {

        double add = 0; 

      for(int x=0; x < testScores; x++)
        add = add + pointerToArray[i].tests[x];
        pointerToArray[i].average = add / testScores;

        //MARK: The course grade will be stored in the grade member structure.
        //After the data entry has been calculated.
    if(pointerToArray[i].average >= 91 && pointerToArray[i].average <= 100)
        pointerToArray[i].grade = 'A';

     else if(pointerToArray[i].average >= 81 && pointerToArray[i].average <= 90)
        pointerToArray[i].grade = 'B';

     else if(pointerToArray[i].average >= 71 && pointerToArray[i].average <= 80)
        pointerToArray[i].grade = 'C';

     else if(pointerToArray[i].average >= 61 && pointerToArray[i].average <= 70)
        pointerToArray[i].grade = 'D';

     else if(pointerToArray[i].average < 60)
        pointerToArray[i].grade = 'F';



        //MARK: Displaying the table to list each students name, ID number, 
         //average test score and the course grade.

        for(int i=0; i < numberOfStudents; i++)
        {

         cout << "Student Name: " << setw(19) << left << pointerToArray[i].studentName <<
         " ID Number: " << setw(19) << pointerToArray[i].id <<
         " Average test score: " <<  setw(15) << pointerToArray[i].average <<
         " Grade: " << setw(15) << pointerToArray[i].grade << endl;

        }


        return 0;

    }



    }
```

Comment: When you tried your solution what happened? Didn't it work? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Your code looks chaotic. Please let you IDE or editor format the code. After doing that, the `if` and the `while` in the first two lines will start in the same column.

Comment: On a side note: it's usually a bad idea to call `new` manually.  In this case, I would recommend using `std::vector` instead of manual memory management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're trying to input negative numbers to the students and test scores, you just need to add a similar while loop to test them as you do bellow for the grades...

```
cout << "How many students?";
cin >> numberOfStudents;
while (numberOfStudents <= 0) {
   cout << "Number of students should be greater than 0";
   cin >> numberOfStudents;
   cout << endl;
 }
cout << endl;
```

As noted in the previous comments, new[] expects size_t, meaning an unsigned number https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Appreciated it.

Answer (score 2):

If negative numbers are entered for `numberOfStudents` or `testsScore`, then

```
student_information *pointerToArray = new student_information[numberOfStudents];
```

or

```
pointerToArray[i].tests = new int[testScores];
```

try to allocate memory with huge amount. When this fails `std::bad_alloc` is `throw`n and OP doesn't `catch` it. Hence, it is catched outside OPs `main()`.

The array size in [`new[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) expects a `size_t` → an unsigned value and silently converts the provided signed. E.g. `-1` becomes `0xffffffff` (32 bit) or even bigger.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int value = -1;
  size_t size = value;
  std::cout << "size: " << size << " = 0x" << std::hex << size << '\n';
  try {
    int *mem = new int[size];
  } catch (const std::exception &error) {
    std::cerr << error.what() << '\n';
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
size: 18446744073709551615 = 0xffffffffffffffff
std::bad_array_new_length
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8e25855ce006e63f)</kbd>

OP should add a check that input numbers are `> 0`.

---

It puzzled me a bit that my sample `throw`s `std::bad_array_new_length` (instead of the `std::bad_alloc` as reported by OP). Investigating a bit into this I found

1. it's precisely documented this way (e.g. in [**cppreference.com**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new))

   > Otherwise, the new-expression does not call the allocation function, and instead throws an exception of type std::bad_array_new_length or derived from it
2. [`std::bad_array_new_length`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_array_new_length) is derived from `std::bad_alloc`.

Comment: I think Asker already figured this much out. That's what they're trying to do in that first bit of code. Pity they didn't go into better detail about what went wrong when they tried it. If they tried it.

Comment: @user4581301 My first reflex was to write a comment. The other days, other people wrote the same as accepted answer. Thus, I try my luck today. ;-)